# How to find the difference between two dates for the same id in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

I have a MySQL database containing a ticket ID, the create time of the ticket and the create time of each interaction between the company operator and the client.

I would like to get the total awaiting time on client and company side for the same ticket ID.

> id      id_ticket      id_sender      time
>
> 1       123             1               2010-04-26 03:32:44
>
> 2       159             1               2010-04-26 03:40:44
>
> 3       983             1               2010-04-26 04:44:26
>
> 4       159             2               2010-04-26 05:12:35
>
> 5       159             1               2010-04-26 06:25:45
>
> 6       123             2               2010-04-26 08:46:12
>
> 7       159             2               2010-04-26 09:36:25
>
> 8       123             1               2010-04-26 12:48:39

id_side is either company or client answer.

Is there a way to do it in MySQL ? Thanks.

[As example, the total awaiting time for customer (id_sender = 1) for the ticket #123 is (2010-04-26 08:46:12 - 2010-04-26 03:32:44) + (2010-04-26 12:48:39 - 2010-04-26 08:46:12) = 18808 + 14547 = 33355 sec.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table to itself, with the join condition that the joined row have the previous highest id for the same ticket_id:

```
select sum(TO_SECONDS(a.time) - TO_SECONDS(b.time)) total_wait
from ticket a
join ticket b on b.id = (
    select max(id)
    from ticket
    where id < a.id
    and id_ticket = a.id_ticket)
where a.id_ticket = 123
```

See a [live demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c4b3/15) using your data, with output: `33355`

---

You could actually get *all* wait times in a similar way:

```
select a.id_ticket, sum(TO_SECONDS(a.time) - TO_SECONDS(b.time)) total_wait
from ticket a
join ticket b on b.id = (
    select max(id)
    from ticket
    where id < a.id
    and id_ticket = a.id_ticket)
group by 1
```

See [SQLFiddle for that](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c4b3/18)

Comment: Perhaps I didn't put that very well. The second is almost perfect. I need the total time for each distinct id_sender.

Comment: I just added "AND id_sender = 2" or "AND id_sender = 1" after the WHERE close in the second query following the customer or company side  and it works like a charm ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id_ticket, TIMEDIFF(MAX(`time`), MIN(`time`))
FROM `table containing ticket ID, create time of ticket and time of interaction`
GROUP BY `id_ticket`
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This query return the total time from MIN to MAX for each ticket. I would like to have separately the time for each ticket for distinct id_sender = 1 and  id_sender = 2.

Comment: Add a `WHERE` clause or additionally groupy by `id_sender`

Comment: I added "WHERE article_sender_type_id <> 2" considering that I have 3 different id_sender and I don't need the number 2 and I like the output ! Thanks again.